# Animate dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript

I am currently creating a little todo list and I had an idea but I do not know how to implement it.

When I add items to my list I want them to .fadeIn('slow') but I am not sure how to make that happen! I know how to $('ul').fadeIn('slow'), but is there a way to make the animation occur when the function todoList.addListHTML() is called?

I originally had:

```
$('ul').fadeIn('slow')
```

Obviously this won't work because the ul does not exist when the page loads.

Here is the code, right now this is very rushed and not refactored or anything:

```
let ul = document.createElement('ul');
ul.id = "todoList";

let todoList = {
  todos: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'],

  displayTodos: function(){
    console.log(this.todos);
  },

  changeTodo: function(position, newValue){
    this.todos[position] = newValue;
    this.displayTodos();
  },

  addTodo: function(todo){
    let unList = document.getElementById('todoList');
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    let span = document.createElement('span');

    span.textContent = todo;
    li.appendChild(span);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    document.body.appendChild(ul);

    this.displayTodos();
  },

  removeTodos: function(position, endRemove){
    this.todos.splice(position, endRemove);
    this.displayTodos();
  },

  doubleList: function(){
    let newArr = [];
    let arrSize = this.todos.length;
    console.log(newArr);

    for(let i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
      newArr.push(this.todos[i]);
      this.todos.push(newArr[i]);
    }
      this.displayTodos();
  },

  addListToHTML(){
    document.body.appendChild(ul);

    console.log(document.body.children);

    for(let i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++){
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      let span = document.createElement('span');

      span.textContent = this.todos[i];
      li.appendChild(span);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  },

  clearList: function(){
    document.body.removeChild(ul);
  }
};
```

Comment: can you provide your current code?

Comment: I've gone ahead and added my code. The only reason I didn't add it before was because I don't have anything written for the idea I am trying to implement yet as anything I've written has not yielded any results at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar with JQuery so there may be a better way to do this.  But whenever I need to animate anything I toggle classes.  So you want this to fade in you should change the opacity from 0 to 1 as you add each item.

```js
var todoList = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
var newElement;

$('#add-list-items').on('click', function() {
    var nextNumber = $('#to-do-list li').length + 1;
    var newHTML = '<li class="Loading">' + 'Item ' + nextNumber + '</li>';
    
    newElement = $(newHTML).appendTo('#to-do-list');
    $(newElement).addClass('Loaded');
});
```

```css
.Loading
{
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation:  fadeout .5s ease-in;
    -moz-animation:     fadeout .5s ease-in;
    -o-animation:       fadeout .5s ease-in;
    animation:          fadeout .5s ease-in;
}

.Loaded
{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation:  fadein 1s ease-in;
    -moz-animation:     fadein 1s ease-in;
    -o-animation:       fadein 1s ease-in;
    animation:          fadein 1s ease-in;
}

@keyframes fadein
{
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein
{
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein
{
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
@-o-keyframes fadein
{
    from { opacity:0; }
    to { opacity:1; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="to-do-list">
</ul>
<input type="button" id="add-list-items" value="Add Items">
```

Comment: Awesome! This should work! I'll try it when I'm back at my pc.